# Probability Curve for the Odds Ratios of a Logit Model

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about plotting a probability curve for a logistic regression model that has multiple predictors. I'm posted this here on SO because I'm wondering about ggplot2 specific solutions, and creating useful graphics from a logit model in ggplot2.

So here is an example =

```
library(car)
mtcars
log <- glm(vs ~ mpg + am, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
summary(log)
```

This provides with the logit coefs (log odds), but I'm wondering how to proceed with predicting for Y=1 for all "levels" of mpg and am in ggplot2. Basically, how do I use ggplot2 to create plots which are useful for interpreting the results of the logit model? I'm particularly wondering about solutions when there are multiple predictors.

EDIT:

I was specifically asking about generating graphs with the predicted values, or odds ratios.

Comment: *If* you weren't trying to do an additive model (i.e. your response was `mpg*am` rather than `mpg+am`) you could just use `ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,vs,colour=factor(am)))+geom_smooth(method="glm",family=binomial)` ... but this doesn't work for your case (alas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(car)
mtcars
#Change your model name because log is also a function
logodds <- glm(vs ~ mpg + am, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
summary(logodds)

library(ggplot2)
new.data = with(mtcars, expand.grid(am = unique(am),
                                    mpg = seq(min(mpg), max(mpg))))

new.data$vs <- predict.glm(logodds, newdata = new.data, type = "response")

ggplot(new.data, aes(mpg, vs, colour = am)) + geom_line(aes(group = am))
```

[image]

Comment: Good call on ```type="response"```.  I forgot about that.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're looking to the predicted Y given different values of mpg and am or just looking to interpret the coefficients?

If you're trying to interpret the coefficients I am a big fan of coefficient plots.

```
require(coefplot)
coefplot(log)
```

That gets you this:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Perhaps this then.

```
preds <- with(mtcars, expand.grid(mpg, am))
names(preds) <- c("mpg", "am")
preds$Score <- predict(object=logMod, newdata=preds, type="response")
ggplot(preds, aes(x=mpg, y=Score, group=am, colour=factor(am))) + geom_line(linetype=2) + scale_color_discrete("am")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my question probably wasn't clear. I was really talking about the predicted values.

Comment: @ATMathew This might be more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your other choice - though not yet using ggplot2 - are plot methods found in Frank Harrell's rms package.  I hope that Harrell will shortly switch to ggplot2 for his graphs, but the set of methods, diagnostic plots, probability plots, coefficient plots, etc. are very useful.